# Two pairs of Carmichael numbers with the same product?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, carmichael-numbers

Suppose there are four integers $p,q,r,s$ such that

$$p \cdot q = r \cdot s$$

and $p,q,r,s$ are all Carmichael numbers. Obviously there are trivial solutions, namely $p=r,q=s$ and $p=s,q=r$. My question is: can you find any non-trivial solution? Can you prove that only trivial solutions exist?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: My goal is to prove that only trivial solutions exist. I tried using Korselt's criterion to get to some sort of contradiction, but I got lost in a bunch of modular equations without being able to conclude much

Comment: There are also solutions , if $p$ and $q$ should be coprime : An example is $$172081\cdot 8719309=1729\cdot 867800701$$

Comment: @Peter Very nice. It would be interesting to know where the question comes from. Is it a competition question? Hopefully not a current one.  Or just a curiosity? Unfortunately nothing is said in the post.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the counterexamples. I was so focused on my goal that I did not the contemplate the possibility of being wrong. @DietrichBurde The question arose because I am studying pseudoprimes for a cryptoscheme. Actually, Carmichael numbers are not so useful for my application, I just thought they might be handier than strong pseudoprimes to start my investigation. My ultimate goal is to find out whether such a result holds for strong pseudoprimes or not.

Comment: @HiddenInPublic Very interesting! You should have added this to your post. Then people would upvote your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found four different Carmichael numbers
\begin{align*}
a & = 7\cdot 31\cdot 73, \\
b & = 7\cdot 13\cdot 31\cdot 61, \\
c & = 37\cdot 73\cdot 181, \\
d & = 13\cdot 37\cdot 61\cdot 181, \\
\end{align*}
which satisfy $ad=bc=7\cdot 13\cdot 31\cdot 37\cdot 61\cdot 73\cdot 181$.